# Error 1053 al querer iniciar un Worker Service

Tags: service-workers

Estoy tratando de iniciar un Worker Service que descargué de git pero me sale el error:

Error 1053: El servicio no respondió a tiempo a la solicitud de inicio o de control.

Leí por ahí que desde el Regedit se puede poner la entrada ServicesPipeTimeout en 86400000 pero sigue sin andar. Que podrá ser?

Muchas gracias.
Raulus.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Estaba pinchando el servicio. Lo ví en el visor de eventos de windows. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado. Estaba pinchando el servicio. Lo ví en el visor de eventos de windows. Gracias!! –